# SQLite: How do I insert values from one table to another, but table2 has extra column I want to populate with a certain word

Tags: sql, sqlite

So let's say `TABLE_1` has 2 columns:

`PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_NUMBER`

Say I want to copy all the rows in `TABLE_1` to `TABLE_2` which has 3 columns:

`PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_TYPE | PRODUCT_NUMBER`

Is it possible to move all the data from `TABLE_1` to `TABLE_2` as well as populate `PRODUCT_TYPE` with the world 'LARGE' using a single insert statement?

I understand that one way would be to `ALTER` the `PRODUCT_TYPE` column in `TABLE_2` to have a default value, but I don't want to do this because I will be inserting other data into this table later which will have a different `PRODUCT_TYPE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use constant expressions in your `SELECT`. This includes `SELECT`s that you execute as part of an insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, PRODUCT_NUMBER)
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, 'LARGE' AS PRODUCT_TYPE, PRODUCT_NUMBER
FROM TABLE_1
```